# Why does Zsh have two processes?

Tags: zsh

When I look at `pstree` output, an instance of zsh is a stack of two processes.

```
 ├─tmux: server─┬─tmux: server
 │              ├─13*[zsh───zsh]
 │              ├─zsh─┬─pstree
 │              │     └─zsh
 │              └─zsh─┬─vim
 │                    └─zsh
```

Here you can see this system's tmux server has 13 zsh's sitting idle at the shell, one running pstree, and one running vim.

When I run a program in one, the child-zsh is a sibling of that program.

I'm curious what this child zsh process's function is.

Comment: does it happen if you use `zsh -f` instead of whatever configuration you've added to `zsh` ?

Comment: I suspect you have some option enabled in `zsh` that requires it to do something continuously or periodically in the background, so it forks a child process to do this. I'm not familiar enough with `zsh` to know what this might be.